# How to clear available items of p:selectOneMenu before adding new items

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am using primefaces SelectOneMenu.

I have this strange issue of the selectonemenu dropdown adding on based on previous selection.

To illustrate  my point, I have a list of department in a selectonemenu dropdown that the staff can select. The bottom selectonemenu dropdown will get populated based on the value selected.

So in the Retail Outlet department, there is 2 sub departments Store Display and Sales and Operations Teams.

[image]

The restaurant department has 3 sub departments namely Kitchen, Serving Teams and Cashiers.
When I select restaurant department, in this case it should only show Kitchen, Serving Teams and Cashiers in the bottom selectonemenu dropdown. See image below.

[image]

Instead, it is adding on to the bottom selectonemenu dropdown.
How do I clear the list to make sure that the previous selection do not appear?

My codes.

```
<p:outputLabel for="department" value="Department: " />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="department" value="#{staffBean.department}" style="width:150px">
                            <p:ajax listener="#{staffBean.onDepartmentChange()}" update="subdepartment" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Department" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{staffBean.returnDepartment(staffBean.staff.location_staff.type)}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="department" />

                        <p:outputLabel for="subdepartment" value="Sub Department: " />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="subdepartment" value="#{staffBean.subDepartment}" style="width:150px">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Sub Department" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{staffBean.listOfSubDepartment}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="subdepartment" />
```

This is my code for onDepartmentChange

```
public void onDepartmentChange() {

        if(department !=null && !department.equals(""))
        {
            listOfSubDepartment = staffSession.getAllSubDepartments(department);
        }
        else
        {
            listOfSubDepartment = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
```

Any help please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this problem by using listOfSubDepartment.clear();